# How long do iTunes credit refunds take?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I got a refund for an app someone purchased with my phone and got email confirmation of the refund but my iTunes balance hasn’t changed. It’s been two days since I received the email. Is this normal or is there something wrong? [image]

Answer (score 2):

It can take up to approx. 14 days - but usually you should have your refund within 3-5 days.

It varies according to the method of payment, which App Store you bought from (i.e. which country), and how busy the App Store is.

Comment: I don't doubt what you're saying, however an authoritative link to an Apple Support article would be nice to include if one exists. After all where did you get this information from? (Rhetorical question.)

Comment: No direct Apple Support article exists for this specific piece of information. You can find the ordinary refund policy for the Apple Store, but that mostly applies to physical purchases. My answer is based on what I have heard from people that they have experienced when asking for refunds. As an app developer, I have had a special interest in that.